# How to convert MySQL DATETIME value to json format in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex

I want to convert the DATETIME value retrieved from MySQL to JSON.

```
Tue Aug 19 2014 16:55:01 GMT+0800 (CST)
```

The resulting JSON should look like this:

```
{'year': yyyy, 'month': MM, 'day': dd, 'hour': hh, 'minute': mm, 'second': ss, 'GMT': GMT}
```

Regular expression seems to be too complex. I don't know how to perform the conversion.

Comment: capture groups using parenthesis `(...)` and replace with `$index` in final JSON string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
var d = new Date("Tue Aug 19 2014 16:55:01 GMT+0800 (CST)");
var year = d.getFullYear();
var date = d.getDate();     //so on so forth.
```

All the date objects are explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). These variables can then be used in your json object.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using regular expression as well. Like in the following snippet.

```
var s = 'Tue Aug 19 2014 16:55:01 GMT+0800 (CST)';
var p = /(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\w+):(\d+):(\d+)\s(\w+).*/;

console.log(s.replace(p, "{'year': $4, 'month': $2, 'day': $1, 'hour': $5, 'minute': $6, 'second': $7, 'GMT': $8}"));
```

Working [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/dekedanayado/1/edit?js,console,output)